# Can't interpret the navigation error on headless browser click in SimpleBrowser

Tags: c#, headless-browser

I'm executing the sample below and getting two different click results. There's no exceptions thrown but the first click produces `SucceededNavigationComplete` and the other `SucceededNavigationError`. When I execute those manually by hand, there's a new window being navigated to, though.

```
Browser browsy = new Browser();
browsy.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0";
browsy.AutoRedirect = true;

string frontPageUrl = ...;
browsy.Navigate(frontPageUrl);
string html1 = browsy.CurrentHtml;

HtmlResult anchor = browsy.Find(ElementType.Anchor, "name", "xxx");
ClickResult result1 = anchor.Click();
string html2 = browsy.CurrentHtml;

HtmlResult button = browsy.Find(ElementType.Button, "name", "yyy");
ClickResult result2 = button.Click();
string html3 = browsy.CurrentHtml;
```

How can I trouble-shoot and and where can I get more info on why the error occurred? I'm rather new to headless browsing so any hint might be of value.

Comment: Where do you see these SucceededNavigationComplete and SucceededNavigationError?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice In the `result1` and `result2`.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is 2 years old, but ...

The most likely reason is that, as suggested, result1 and result2 are invalid. Find() will always return an HtmlResult object, but that object may not be what you expect. Before doing *anything* with the HtmlResult returned from a call to Find(), you should always validate the HtmlResult. For example:

```
HtmlResult anchor = browsy.Find(ElementType.Anchor, "name", "xxx");
if (anchor.Exists)
{
    ClickResult result1 = anchor.Click();
    string html2 = browsy.CurrentHtml;
}
```

The next logical question is "why are result1 and result 2 invalid?" This is very likely (a near certainty) because the HTML the browser is rendering is not the HTML that it received from the server. Almost all modern websites use DOM manipulation with JavaScript resulting in the rendered HTML being very different than the source HTML. The next thing to verify is that the anchor and/or button that you are trying to Find() exists in the source HTML. SimpleBrowser does not support JavaScript and, as a result, does not perform any DOM manipulation. SimpleBrowser only sees the source HTML document.